# List com 3 elementos c++

Tags: c++, lista, vector

Estou usando list em c++, e no que eu penso a estrutura dela interna deve conter:

> Conteudo
>   ponteiro para o próximo elemento

É possível colocar mais uma variável dentro dessa estrutura, como o exemplo abaixo?

> Conteudo
>   variável string
>   ponteiro para o próximo elemento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não, não é possível modificar a biblioteca padrão. Qualquer coisa do gênero é proibido. Você pode, entretanto, ter sua variável string como parte do elemento do contêiner:

```
struct Conteudo
{
    std::string str;
};
```

E usá-la como `std::list<Conteudo>`.